# Need to redirect to same jsp after submiting

Tags: jsp, servlets

i am using the jsp servlet a simple form which has two submit button.
first submit will take few fields from the form and fetch the result and second will finally submit the whole form.My problem is i am loosing all the form fields after submit, i want to retain that.
How i am doing:
After the first request came to servlet i am calling

```
request.getRequestDispatcher("myJsp.jsp").forward(request,response);
```

how can i retrieve the form fields which are already filled without using ajax.

Here is my jsp file

```
<FORM id="form" METHOD="POST" ACTION="action">

        <TABLE class="baseFrame">            
            <TR>
                <TD>UserName</TD>
                <TD><INPUT TYPE="text" NAME="txtUser" SIZE="25"  ></TD>
            </TR>
            <TR>
                <TD>Password</TD>
                <TD><INPUT TYPE="password" NAME="txtPass" SIZE="25" ></TD>
            </TR>
            <TR>
                <TD>Docbase</TD>
                <TD><INPUT TYPE="text" NAME="txtDocbase" SIZE="25" ></TD>
            </TR>
                <TR>
              <TD><INPUT TYPE="Submit"  Value="GetObjects" NAME="getObject" /></TD>
            </TR> 
            <TR>
                <TD>R_Object_ID's</TD>

                <TD><textarea rows= "10" cols = "30" name="idList" id="" >
                    <c:forEach items='${rObjIds}' var='varObj'>
                        <c:out value="${varObj}"/>
                    </c:forEach>
                    </textarea>
                </TD>
            </TR>
            <TR>
                <TD></TD>
                <TD><INPUT TYPE="Submit"  Value="Syndicate Bulk" NAME="Run_DFS" /></TD>
            </TR>
        </form>
```

and in my servlet I am using

```
protected void doPost( HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response ) throws ServletException, IOException
    {
        logger.info("Coming to do post method");
        if(request.getParameter("getObject") != null){
        ArrayList<String> objIds = new ArrayList<String>();
        objIds = getObjectIds();
        request.setAttribute("rObjIds", objIds);
        this.getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/bulk_syndication_utility.jsp").forward(request,response);
    }
        else if(request.getParameter("Run_DFS") != null){
        logger.info("going to syndicate object ids");   
        doJob();
        }       
request.getRequestDispatcher("bulk_syndication_utility.jsp").forward(request,response);
    }
```

To retain values after first click I used value="${fn:escapeXml(param.txtUser)}but I think I cant reatain password using that So that also didn't fixed it.

Comment: you can have a *form backing object* for you first form. Then bind the first form object to the `request.setAttribute()` and finally `forward` the request to the next `form`.

Comment: Thanks Erfan for your response actually am using the servlet for first time can you be more specific or share some sample around this, that will be really helpful .

Comment: in that case, post you `domain` and `servlet` class code. Need to look at those before giving you a specific answer.

Comment: Hi Erfan I just updated the code please have a look.

Comment: You first need to use `JSTL`. That will bind the data to your `POJO` class. Learn [how to use JSLT to bind form data into a POJO](https://www.journaldev.com/2090/jstl-tutorial-jstl-tags-example).